# copy/paste from local windows to Raspberry Pi TightVNCserver?

Tags: raspbian, vnc

copy paste from windows to Raspberry Pi TightVNCserver isn't working.

On the local windows i tried tightVNCViewer and realvnc.

In realvnc -> options -> Inputs -> Share clipboard text with VNC Server is checked.

On the Raspberry Pi, vncconfig isn't working -> Command not found.

According to previous solution of using autocutsel i need to configure file under 
/home/pi/.vnc/xstartup but i don't have .vnc directory at all.

Can someone help me? I'm new in this field.

Comment: Have you tried creating the directory and file needed using mkdir and touch commands respectively?

Comment: the directory is there, but i can't edit it from raspberry pi. i found workaround, by editing it using winSCP from my computer. 
i added the following line, but it doesn't work (even after restart)
autocutsel -fork